# why can I not use break?

Tags: c++, for-loop, break

I have written the following code for the problem:

> Alice has an array of NN integers — A_1, A_2, ..., A_N. She wants the product of all the elements of the array to be a non-negative integer. That is, it can be either 00 or positive. But she doesn't want it to be negative.
>
> To do this, she is willing to remove some elements of the array. Determine the minimum number of elements that she will have to remove to make the product of the array's elements non-negative.

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;cin>>n;
        int res=0;
        bool flag=false;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
            int f;cin>>f;
            if(f<0){
                res++;
            }
            if(f==0){
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(res%2==0 || flag==true){
                cout<<0<<endl;
            }
        else{
                cout<<1<<endl;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that if I remove the break statement, the code will get correct answer for all test cases. But why can I not use break, as it will only terminate the for loop?

Comment: can you explain how the code works? Why does it produce the correct output?

Comment: @tobias_k because negative * negative = positive. Only when the number of negatives is odd one has to be removed

Comment: Algorithm: calculate the product. answer is `elements_remove_count = product < 0.0 ? 1 : 0`. Are you sure you described the problem correctly? Or if this is some kind of a trick question?

Comment: @hyde yes its a trick question. It took me some time to get it as well. When there is a 0, the product of all element is 0, nothing has to be removed. When there is a odd number of negative elements one has to be removed. When there is an even number nothing has to be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read all input even if you do know the answer already:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
        int f;cin>>f;
           // ^^ ----------- !!!
```

If you break from that loop then the numbers for the current test case are still in the stream, waiting to be read. And you do read them for the next test case.

Consider this input for two test cases

```
 0 1 2 3
 2 4 0 5 1 2 3 4
```

But your code with the `break` will read for the two test cases this:

```
 0
 1 2 3 2 4 0
```

When you know the answer already you can `continue` the loop after reading input:

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
        int f;
        cin>>f;
        if (flag) continue;
        // ...
```